# How to set Application Insights AuthenticatedUserId for DependencyTelemetry?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Within an Azure Function I am submitting custom telemetry.

```
//First an event
EventTelemetry eventTelemetry = new EventTelemetry()
{
    Name = $"Authenticated user: {portalUser.FullName} - ({portalUser.Id})"
};

ConfigureTelemetry(eventTelemetry);

TelemetryClient.TrackEvent(eventTelemetry);

//Then a dependency
DependencyTelemetry dependencyTelemetry = new DependencyTelemetry()
{
    Type = "SOAP",
    Name = name,
    Target = target,
    Data = data,
    Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
    Success = success
};

ConfigureTelemetry(dependencyTelemetry);

TelemetryClient.TrackDependency(dependencyTelemetry);

...

//Set shared properties
void ConfigureTelemetry(ITelemetry telemetry)
{
    telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = FunctionSettings.InvocationId;
    telemetry.Context.Operation.ParentId = FunctionSettings.InvocationId;
    telemetry.Context.Operation.Name = FunctionSettings.FunctionName;

    telemetry.Context.User.Id = PortalUser.Id.ToString();
    telemetry.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = PortalUser.Id.ToString();
}
```

The event and dependency are succesfully tracked in Application Insights, however the `DependencyTelemetry` is missing the `Id` and `AuthenticatedUserId` information.

Is `user_id` and `user_authenticatedid` supported for dependencies?

---

In response to questions:

> Do you any TelemetryInitializer or TelemetryProcessor which is
>   modifying these fields as well?

No. Just what is shown in the code above.

> How do you create the instance of TelemetryClient?

```
return new TelemetryClient()
{
    InstrumentationKey = ApplicationSettings.ApplicationInsightsKey
};
```

> In my opinion you have to set the context for the instance

I have also tried that but same result, in which case my code looks more like this:

```
void ConfigureTelemetry()
{
    ...
    TelemetryClient.Context.User.Id = PortalUser.Id.ToString();
    TelemetryClient.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = PortalUser.Id.ToString();
}
```

> please also share an example for the event and dependency shown in Application Insights's analytics view

In these examples I wasn't trying to set `user_id' but that does work for events.

customEvents

```
timestamp [UTC] | 2018-07-11T16:14:15.48Z   
name | Authenticated user: Cenajog2 Cenajog2 - (127a897f-d16f-e811-810a-3863bb343b78)   
itemType | customEvent  
operation_Name | TestOperation
operation_Id | c03d657f-6b0b-483e-9a32-c592fd2af701 
operation_ParentId | c03d657f-6b0b-483e-9a32-c592fd2af701   
user_AuthenticatedId | 127a897f-d16f-e811-810a-3863bb343b78 
client_Type | PC    
client_IP | 0.0.0.0 
client_City | London    
client_StateOrProvince | England    
client_CountryOrRegion | United Kingdom 
cloud_RoleInstance | RD00155D8C9B54 
appId | 824c86f8-29be-4a01-b242-44bfe1915520    
appName | dev
iKey | 9921a9e7-0c07-49fd-bd71-a9e76b9906bc 
sdkVersion | dotnet:2.5.1-172   
itemId | 7b2708c1-8525-11e8-a89a-2fa60245d417   
itemCount | 1
```

dependencies

```
timestamp [UTC] | 2018-07-11T16:14:15.48Z   
id | yP475Jc3ZwY=   
target | Development    
type | SOAP 
name | RetrieveMultiple 
success | True  
performanceBucket | >=5min  
itemType | dependency   
operation_Name | TestOperation
operation_Id | c03d657f-6b0b-483e-9a32-c592fd2af701 
operation_ParentId | c03d657f-6b0b-483e-9a32-c592fd2af701
client_Type | PC
client_IP | 0.0.0.0
client_City | London
client_StateOrProvince | England
client_CountryOrRegion | United Kingdom
cloud_RoleInstance | RD00155D8C9B54
appId | 824c86f8-29be-4a01-b242-44bfe1915520
appName | dev
iKey | 9921a9e7-0c07-49fd-bd71-a9e76b9906bc
sdkVersion | dotnet:2.5.1-172
itemId | 7b2708c0-8525-11e8-a89a-2fa60245d417
itemCount | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserId` and `UserAuthenticatedUserId` are supported for all types, including `DependencyTelemetry`.  So the above code should show userid etc for Dependencies as well, if `PortalUser.Id.ToString();` returns non empty value.

Do you any `TelemetryInitializer` or `TelemetryProcessor` which is modifying these fields as well?

Comment: Thanks, edited my question in response to your questions.

Comment: In the end there was a simple logical error in my application logic which once resolved meant `UserAuthenticatedUserId` was set correctly. For future readers, facing a similar issue, check out the Visual Studio Debug Output whilst debugging, it lists all the information sent to Application Insights.

Answer (score 0):

for your specific scenario, where you are using Application Insights in Azure Functions:

- user_authenticatedid is supported
- user_id is set to "Azure" by default

How do you create the instance of TelemetryClient?
In my opinion you have to set the context for the instance:

```
private static string key = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
private static TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = key };
telemetry.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = "whatEver";
```

Comment: Thanks, edited my question in response to your questions. I've not seen user_id set to Azure in any circumstance.

Comment: please also share an example for the event and dependency shown in Application Insights's analytics view, so we can see the actual result

Comment: when you go to Application Insights's analytics view, select dependencies on the left and expand the fields, do you see the related fields? Or when you query for dependencies, check if the fields are selected (visible) in the colums chooser. Sometimes not all available fields are shown in the query result

Comment: Pretty sure I was displaying all columns (I didnt specify any columns), the data in my question is all populated fields I believe.